# about effective java 2 char 10 item 66

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class StopMultiThread {
    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int testNum = 100;
        List<Boolean> result = new ArrayList<>(testNum);
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(testNum);
        for (int i = 0; i < testNum; i++) {
            int copy = i;
            Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int j = 0;
                    while (!stopRequested) {
//                        j++;
                        System.out.println("brokenStopMultiThread " + copy + " " + j++);
                    }
                    long runTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - beginTime;
                    System.out.println("brokenStopMultiThread " + copy + " run " + runTime);
                    result.add(runTime < 1500);
                    countDownLatch.countDown();
                }
            });
            backgroundThread.start();
        }
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
        countDownLatch.await();
        System.out.println("result:" + result);
        int expectedTimes = 0;
        for (Boolean b : result)
            if (b)
                expectedTimes++;
        System.out.println("expectedTimes:" + expectedTimes + ", brokenTimes:" + (result.size() - expectedTimes));
    }
}
```

---

enviroment

java version "1.8.0_77"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)

code above can stop thread normally, but code below can not, why?

```
while (!stopRequested) {
    j++;
    // System.out.println("brokenStopMultiThread " + copy + " " + j++);
}
```

---

test 5 times

code A will result in

expectedTimes:23, brokenTimes:977

expectedTimes:45, brokenTimes:955

expectedTimes:174, brokenTimes:825

expectedTimes:207, brokenTimes:793

expectedTimes:175, brokenTimes:825

code A

```
while (!stopRequested) {
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    j++;
//  System.out.println("brokenStopMultiThread " + copy + " " + j++);
}
```

code B will result in

expectedTimes:1000, brokenTimes:0

expectedTimes:999, brokenTimes:0

expectedTimes:1000, brokenTimes:0

expectedTimes:1000, brokenTimes:0

expectedTimes:1000, brokenTimes:0

code B

```
while (!stopRequested) {
    /*try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    j++;*/
    System.out.println("brokenStopMultiThread " + copy + " " + j++);
}
```

all threads are stopped with different runTime, maybe liveness failure does not occur easily on jdk8

Comment: There's a volatile hidden somewhere inside the system `PrintWriter`?

Comment: this loop is too tight; add a mini sleep in here

Comment: @ScaryWombat thank you, that works

Comment: @chrylis java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String) has a synchronized code block, but that is not the reason

Comment: @omottec Why isn't it, since there's a `println` in every thread?

Comment: java.io.PrintStream#println(java.lang.String) has a synchronized code block,  so the loop is not tight, not the PrintWriter or volatile, but thanks for your prompt reply @chrylis

Comment: @omottec without the println, the boolean variable probably gets hoisted. With the println it isn't because of the synchronized block.

Comment: @assylias thank you, change the testNum to 1000, the result is[expectedTimes:1000, brokenTimes:0],  liveness failure does not occur, the code is just used for test, in productive environment, volatile, synchronized modifier or AtomicBoolean will be used

Comment: @assylias I think you are right, thank you